# How to activate and or install plugins on CKEditor 5 on Vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I need to activate PastFromOffice plugins on CKEditor on Vue. This is how I manage to work.
I have installed "npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office" I understand that this plugins is previously install on the classic CKEditor.

```
<template>
   <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
</template>

<script>
   import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
   import VueCkeditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'

   console.log(ClassicEditor.defaultConfig.toolbar);
   export default {
       components: {
           ckeditor: VueCkeditor.component
       },
       data(){
           return {
               editor: ClassicEditor,
               editorData: '<p>Content of the editor.</p>',
               editorConfig: {
                   /*plugins: [
                       'PasteFromOffice'
                   ],*/
               }
           }
       }
   }
</script>
```

When I apply the plugin like in the comment I get an empty input type text box and many console.logs claiming "The requested toolbar item is unavailable."

And if I add:
"import PasteFromOffice from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office/src/pastefromoffice';"
I get this error:
"ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated."

Any keywords for me to google or ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I think your set up is not correct.

Comment: sorry, my previous answer was really out of date, check my update answer. so classic version already includes PasteFromOffice so you do not need to configure anything.

Comment: Thanks man. Ok, this way works, I got the editor on page but when I add 
`editorConfig: { plugins: [ 'PasteFromOffice' ] } }`
I get the same errors about the toolbar (that can not find italic, bold...) and on page an empty input type text field.

Comment: Ckeditor documentation says that "This warning usually shows up when the Plugin which is supposed to provide a toolbar item has not been loaded or there is a typo in the configuration." So may be my PasteFromOffice is not providing a toolbar?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<template>
  <div class="editor">
    <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

export default {
  name: "Editor",
  data() {
    return {
      editor: ClassicEditor,
      editorData: "<p>Content of the editor.</p>",
      }
    }
};
</script>
```

```js
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue'
import Editor from './editor'
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue";

Vue.use(CKEditor);

new Vue({
    el : '#root',
    components: { Editor },
})
```

```html
    <div id="root">
        <editor></editor>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. I actually thought about it 2 minutes and figure it out hehe. But now I'm not getting anything, not input text or errors o.O

Comment: Exactly. The code you gave me has a couple extra of curly brackets, so I took them out and after that I don't have editor or error on the console.

Comment: No, this is all I have on console (normal stuffs):
"You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not parse content for http://advoodle.localhost/contracts/Spinner.vue.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"